# How to subset data while excluding certain values?

Tags: r

I am picking a value (x) from column A and looking for a corresponding value in column B (y). I then want to find out if the value in column B (y) corresponds with any other value in column A. I do not, however, want to include the original query value of x.

This is slightly complicated because I am trying to do these searches with multiple values simultaneously using lapply

```
x<-1
result<-data[data$a==x,"b"] 

result1<- lapply(unique(as.numeric(unlist(result))), function(f)     
data[data$b==f,"a"])
```

the above code works, but result1 still returns values where column b=x.
I've tried using ! to avoid including this value from column a, but when it works it seems to change my out put from numerical to true/false.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this get you what you want?  `data[(data$b %in% result) & (data$a !x),"a"]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
result1<- lapply(unique(as.numeric(unlist(result))), function(f) x[x$b==f & x$a!=n,"a"])
```

fixed it!

Comment: Please add some explanation for the others.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in two parts.  First, filter out everything but the values of "a" and "b" you are interested in

```
tmp_data <- data[(data$b %in% result) & data$a !x,]
```

Then, create your list output from that:

```
list_of_bs <- lapply(split(tmp_data, data$a), function(df) df$b)
```